# WASCE data source encryption and integrity configuration

Tags: java, oracle, encryption, websphere, websphere-ce

I have created a database pool on WASCE 3.0.0.3 (WebSphere Application Server Community Edition) which i am using through JNDI. I want to set oracle network data encryption and integrity properties for this database pool. The properties i want to set in particular are oracle.net.encryption_client and oracle.net.encryption_types_client.

How can I set these properties? I do not see any option to set these properties while creating the connection pool and I cannot find any documentation related to the same.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot find any documentation on how to do this because [WAS 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server#Version_history) went out of service in 2003, so any documentation for it is long gone.

If you upgrade to a newer version of WAS traditional (or [Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/)), you will find much more documentation and people willing to help you. Additionally, in WAS 6.1 an admin console (UI) was added, which will probably walk you through what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Andy, the question is about WASCE 3, not WAS 3.0. Unfortunately, we cannot upgrade/change to WAS.